# php.ini not being read with windows 7 installation

Tags: iis-7, windows-7, php

I have installed php successfully on a Windows 7 machine but I can not for the life of me get it to read the php.ini file.

I have uncommented out the line for php to use mysql and when I run phpinfo(), it never shows up.

I have checked to make sure there is only one php.ini file on my entire c:\ drive and it's sitting in my c:\windows folder.

has anyone else run into this and know of a solution to get php to read the .ini so that I can enable some extensions (mysql etc)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the following:

1. Make sure you only have one `php.ini` file. It should be in the same folder as `php.exe`, `php-cgi.exe` and `php-win.exe`. It's worth checking your `c:\windows` and `c:\windows\system32` folders. If you find a `php.ini` in there or anywhere else on the `PATH` other than the PHP install folder then delete them.

   A handy way to check this is to run `where php.ini` from the command prompt.
2. Add your PHP install and extensions folders to the system `PATH`: For example - `c:\php` and `c:\php\ext`
3. Edit your `php.ini` file and ensure that the `extension_dir` directive points to the extensions folder: `extension_dir=c:\php\ext`

This should get you going. If you still find that extensions aren't being loaded then prepend the extension with `ext/`. For example:

`extension=ext/php_mysql.dll`

You don't indicate if you're using FastCGI to launch PHP.

If you're just mapping the `.php` extension directly to `php-cgi.exe` or you're using FastCGI but haven't specified a `monitorChangesTo` attribute then you need to kill any `php-cgi.exe` processes to force a re-read of `php.ini` after any changes (or do an `IISRESET`).

If you're using FastCGI on Windows 7 (or IIS 7.5 generally) then you can trigger recycling of FastCGI whenever your `php.ini` file changes by specifying a the path to the `php.ini` file in the `monitorChangesTo` attribute. This is also configurable through IIS Manager under the FastCGI Settings applet.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same error.  When I tried running php -m from the command line, it was pulling up the appropriate modules, so I knew the right php.ini was being loaded.

However, on the webserver It kept pulling up my php root folder as the extension_dir no matter what I changed.

I did a couple of things and it seemed to resolve it.

1st, I made sure that the path my extensions had IIS_USer read rights.  I don't know if this had anything to do with it working or not, as this by itself did nothing.

2nd, I went back into the IIS Manager, loaded up the Handler Mappings that I had used to initially set up the php handler to use FastCGI.  I didn't have to actually change anything, but by bringing up the dialogue box, and saving it, it asked for confirmation. 
After that, I went back to my phpinfo() page, and it pulled up the right information regarding the extensions_dir.

I hope this helps someone down the road.

Comment: Just ran into the same issue after upgrading my php version and forgot I changed the folder name. So make sure that the path to the executable is correct on the FastCGI module in Handler Mappings